# RSA decryption using "pyca/cryptography" getting error "AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'decrypt'"

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography

I am using below code to decrypt message  But getting below error "error "AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'decrypt'".

I followed below documentation https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.html#encryption.
Little help to solve this issue appreciated.
Getting error while decrypting message.

```
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization as crypto_serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend as crypto_default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
key = rsa.generate_private_key(
        backend=crypto_default_backend(),
        public_exponent=65537,
        key_size=2048
    )
print ("#############################--KEY--#########################################")
print (key)

# private_key = key.private_bytes(
#     encoding=crypto_serialization.Encoding.PEM,
#     format=crypto_serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
#     encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
#     )
# print ("#############################--PRIVATE KEY--#########################################")
# print (private_key.splitlines()[0])

public_key = key.public_key()
print ("#############################--PUBLIC KEY--#########################################")
print (public_key.splitlines()[0])

print ("#############################--ENCRYPT MESSAGE USING PUBLIC KEY--#########################################")

message = b"encrypted data"

ciphertext = public_key.encrypt(
    message,
    padding.PKCS1v15()
)

print (ciphertext)
print ("#############################--DECRYPT MESSAGE USING PUBLIC KEY--#########################################")

plaintext = key.decrypt(
    ciphertext,
    padding.PKCS1v15(
    )
)
print (plaintext)
```

Comment: `private_key` is a bytes object, namely the serialized private key. `key` is the object with the right attributes for what you're trying to do. I'm not sure why you created `private_key` at all.

Comment: I want to do encryption / decryption using RSA.   Using public key I want to decrypt message and using private key I want to decrypt.

Comment: The [`PKCS1v15`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.html#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.padding.PKCS1v15) class corresponds to PKCS#1 v1.5 Padding and does not expect any parameters. The parameters you use are valid in the context of OAEP, represented by the [`OAEP`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.html#cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.padding.OAEP) class.

Comment: Yes .. Able to solve issue using "key" and removing parameters from PKCS1v15.   Thanks